# Determining ConnectionString for DataRecordset.Add()

Tags: vba, connection, visio

The official documentation states the following for both the DataRecordsets.Add() method and the DataConnection.ConnectionString property:

> The easiest way to determine an appropriate connection string for a particular data source is to use the **Data Selector Wizard** in the Visio user interface (UI) to make the same connection, recording a macro while running the wizard, and then copying the connection string from the macro code.

I cannot determine what the 'Data Selector Wizard' is, how to access it, or how to record a macro while using it. Could anyone help me here? There are no references to this wizard in the online documentation. I tried using the 'Create' button under the Data ribbon tab, but I am unable to record a macro while using this wizard. Otherwise, I have found no other information on how to properly create this connection string.

I am trying to connect to an Excel spreadsheet, and the example code has a connection string build command:

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "User ID=Admin;" _
                       & "Data Source=" + strOfficePath + "SAMPLES\1033\ORGDATA.XLS;" _
                       & "Mode=Read;" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MaxScanRows=0;Excel 12.0;"";" _
                       & "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=34;"
```

It is unclear whether this code snippet is sufficient for all cases of trying to connect to an Excel sheet. For instance, if I simply change value associated with 'Data Source', will this always connect properly?

Answer (score 0):

---

1. Convert your visio file to a 'macro-enabled' version

Use save-as and select the macro enabled version (.vsdm)

---

2. Enable the 'Developer' ribbon tab

Go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Ensure 'Developer' is both added and enabled

---

3. Start recoding a macro

On the 'Developer' ribbon tab, click Record Macro. Name the macro if you wish and click 'OK'

---

4. Run the Data Selection Wizard

On the 'Data' ribbon tab, in the External Data group, select "Custom Import". Follow along to choose the excel file, the worksheet, and the data range you want to use. Click 'Finish'

---

5. Stop the macro

On the 'Developer' ribbon tab click Stop Recording

---

6. Open VBA and copy the connection string

On the 'Developer' ribbon tab click 'Visual Basic'. Expand the 'Modules' folder in the project tree (left-top of window). Double-click 'NewMacros'. Copy the long string following 'Application.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets.Add' starting with the double-quote and ending on the double-quote just before the first comma that is not inside quotation (copy the entire first argument passed to the DataRecordsets.Add method. Arguments are separated by commas).

---

7. Utilize the connection string

```
Public Sub AddDataRecordset()

    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strCommand As String
    Dim strOfficePath As String
    Dim vsoDataRecordset As Visio.DataRecordset
    strOfficePath = Enter the Excel File Path Here or Use 'Visio.Application.Path' to get the same path as the Visio file
    strConnection = Paste the Connection String Here
    strCommand = "SELECT * FROM `YourWorksheetName$`"
    Set vsoDataRecordset = ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets.Add(strConnection, strCommand, 0, "CustomNameForImportedData")

End Sub
```